RTMP Streaming and Authentication using NGINX
I have created RTMP server using NGINX and it is working fine.
I am using the following URL to monitor the stream currently: rtmp://VM_IP:1935/front/stream
But, to allow more than one device to stream and monitor streams from all cameras separately, I wanted to modify the URL.
Something like this: rtmp://VM_IP:1935/front/stream/{device_id}
What is the best approach to achieve this?
I have already tried an API which takes two arguments (device id and encoder key (for authentication)) and returns 200 if device id is present and encoder key matches the one, I defined.
I though using this approach I can create a URL and can view the stream to the URL I want.
But this is not working, or I am doing something wrong.
If you have any suggestions, kindly guide me.
